# How to automate creation of Tags on BitBucket from Jenkins using WebHooks?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-api

Is there any way to to support automatic tag creation on Bitbucket via Jenkins pipeline?

I know how to build a branch a Tag is created or a push is done to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Git Publisher addon in the Post-build Actions to do this. It does a lot more than just auto pushing tags but that is what I use it for. Right now, I have it set to push the build number as a tag to the branch that is being used.